# Invalid argument: maximum call for stack size exceeds

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my home screen dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './components/body.dart';
import '../model/product.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  get product => this.product;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: buildBody(),
    );
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black), onPressed: () {}), //iconbutton
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black), onPressed: () {}), //iconbutton
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.black), onPressed: () {}), //iconbutton
      ], //<widget>
    ); //appBar
  }

  Body buildBody() {
    return Body(product: this.product);
  }
}
```

error showing during running is

get product packages/shoppingapp/screens/home_screen.dart 6:23

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6083:14  mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4599:16  performRebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4267:5   rebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4553:5   [_firstBuild]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1104:16

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2535:19  buildScope

packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1103:12    attachToRenderTree

packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 936:24     attachRootWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 917:7

dart:sdk_internal 25312:11                           internalCallback
error showing in emulator during testing.

Invalid argument: maximum call for stack size exceeds

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../model/product.dart';
import '../../../constants.dart';
import 'add_to_cart.dart';
import 'color_and_size.dart';
import 'description.dart';
import 'product_title_with_image.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/screens/details/components/counter_with_fav_btn.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  const Body({Key? key, required this.product}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: size.height,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * 12, left: kDefaultPadding, right: kDefaultPadding), //edgeinsets
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * 0.3),
                  height: 500,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white, //boxdecoration
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(24),
                    ), //boxdecoration
                  ), //borderradius
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ColorAndSize(product: product), //colorand size
                      SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding / 2), //sizedbox
                      Description(product: product),
                      SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding / 2), //sizedbox
                      CounterWithFavBtn(), //counterwithfavbtn
                      SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding / 2), //sizedbox
                      AddToCart(product: product), //addtocart
                    ], //widget
                  ), //column
                ), //container
                ProductTitleWithImage(product: product),
              ], //widget
            ), //stack
          ), //sizedbox
        ], //widget
      ), //column
    ); //singlechildscrollview
  }
}
```

any help is useful
thank you

Comment: your error is probably somewhere else on the code. Can you provide us with the full error stack? also, the stack trace probably references some part of your code, then show us too

Comment: What does this do? `get product => this.product;` this looks to me like a recursive getter, which would fall in line with your error

Comment: Congratulations on having an actual stack overrflow.

Answer (score 1):

You got recursive getter

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  get product => this.product; // <—
```

Use this lint rule
[recursive getter](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/recursive_getters.html) to avoid this happening again

Comment: this is not working. this getting the same error. can you please tell any other solution